# Android Studio errror tryin to get an screenshot : "Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF"

Tags: android, android-studio, screenshot

I'm trying to get screenshots from my device from Android Studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

but i get the message

> "Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot from device: EOF"

I tried unplugging my device and restarting Android Studio with no success.

¿How to solve this problem without having to restart my pc?

Comment: pls, try this my solution

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm this bug is still present in the latest adb.exe.

The only working solution at this moment is replacing adb.exe with the last working version. You can find it inside this zip:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.0-windows.zip

Close Android Studio, then extract the file **adb.exe** (nothing else!) and override the faultly adb.exe at your platform-tools folder.

Default path for adb in Windows:

C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\

Finally, just open Android Studio again, and enjoy using the Screen Capture feature again.

Comment: Thank you. Its a shame having to work like this. I had a sequence of 5 such problems solving it with a hack. I see a very bad future ...

Answer (score 1):

I have found two solutions:

At the beginning I tought that the problem would be the [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) but the ADB was running.

**I)** Open task manager, end the process and tried again succesfully.

[image]

**II)**

I look for the process in the Task Manager to stop the process:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

and then i searched into my Android SDK folder `/platform-tools/` directory for the `adb.exe` to start the process again.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

now i can get the screenshots.

Comment: Not Working for me

Comment: not woorking for me. There seems no solution. What a shame.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove security flag form activities! It helped for me (If not try to restart Android Studio too).

```
// getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```